# IE - Image resizing not working as imagined (-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;)

Tags: css

Currently, I'm scaling a 118x118 pixel PNG graphic to 19x19 and it looks terrible in IE7.
Just to note, I'm utilizing -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;

** Does IE generally not work as intended with PNGs?

Thanks

Comment: * Does IE generally not work as intended with PNGs? - Generally, yes. Works better in IE8/9.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're scaling as opposed to creating two separate graphics? And, if you're doing this with several images on the page, performance issues will arise. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251805/whats-the-performance-impact-of-using-bicubic-interpolation-in-ie

Comment: JavaScript is appending a play overlay graphic that scales down depending on the container size. I'm trying to avoid mapping various image sizes in the JavaScript (keep the JS simple).

Answer (score 2):

In general, trying to deliver a 120-ish pixel image and display it to the user at 20-ish pixels is not the best idea.  You're going to have high overhead from the loading of the image that you don't really need, plus it's nearly always going to scale at a much lower quality than you could get from a rasterized image (and you're sending vector)

It's also not the best idea to be doing things so proprietary as using Microsoft's "special" functions. Yes, they work.  But again, you're sending additional overhead to support one browser that's losing market share by the day.  Insist on w3 standard functionality to do your work and everyone will be happier in the long run....especially the person who picks up your legacy code.

If you HAVE to do it this way, make use of an image manipulation library like GD or ImageMagick.  Or, more simply, take the time to properly format your image or icon down with Photoshop, Gimp, or the like.  For 2-3 minutes' worth of work, you'll have a happier user and be able to move on to more important things.

Comment: +1 for the "support one browser that's losing market share by the day" part!